# I want to scroll up after the all childs of ListView have been scrolled up, parent widget of listview is SingleChildScrollView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-scrollbar

I have SingleChildScrollView as a parent and in that, I have two listviews each list view is wrapped with SizedBox with a specific height (like 700), what I want is, when I scroll up all the views that are in the first list, the first Listview should scroll up and then I'll be able to scroll next Listview, Please have a look into the code below.
Your help means a lot to me.
Thank you in advance.
*Note: I'm getting this required behavior in chrome but not on a mobile device*

```
SingleChildScrollView( child: Column(children: [


      SizedBox(
        height: 700,
        child:ListView.builder(
            itemCount:
          20, itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return const ListTile(leading: Icon(Icons.icecream,
              color: Colors.amber,), title: Text("Ice Cream"),);
          },),
        ),
     
      
      SizedBox(
        height: 300,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20, itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.cake, color: Colors.red,),
            title: Text("Cake"),);
        },),
      ),


    ],),)
```

Comment: 1 question, why dont you use single ListView for all?

Comment: because I have a specific requirement, I have to show two listviews at a specific height.

Comment: In your case, I might disable the last ListView and use  Column

Comment: I'm getting this required behavior in chrome but not on a mobile device, I don't know why it's not working on a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Do something like this on the Controllers:

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ScrollingBehaviourInDart extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollingBehaviourInDart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScrollingBehaviourInDart> createState() =>
      _ScrollingBehaviourInDartState();
}

class _ScrollingBehaviourInDartState extends State<ScrollingBehaviourInDart> {
  late ScrollController _sc1;
  late ScrollController _sc2;
  late ScrollController _sc3;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _sc1 = ScrollController();
    _sc2 = ScrollController();
    _sc3 = ScrollController();
    var _pr = Provider.of<MyScrollProvider>(context, listen: false);
    _sc1.addListener(() {
      log("SC1::::::::::: " + _sc1.position.pixels.toString());
      if (_sc1.position.pixels == _sc1.position.minScrollExtent) {
        print("OK");
        _pr.changePhysics(enableScrolling: true);
      }
    });
    _sc2.addListener(() {
      if (_sc2.offset == _sc2.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        _pr.changePhysics(enableScrolling: false);
        log("YAAA");
      }
    });

    _sc3.addListener(() {
      log("SC3::::::::::: " + _sc3.position.pixels.toString());
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _sc1.dispose();
    _sc2.dispose();
    _sc3.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
        body: SizedBox(
          height: _size.height,
          child: Consumer<MyScrollProvider>(
            builder: (context, myScrollProvider, _) => SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _sc1,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _size.height * 0.5,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: _sc2,
                      physics: myScrollProvider.enablePrimaryScroll
                          ? const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
                          : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: 20,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return const ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(
                            Icons.icecream,
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                          title: Text("Ice Cream"),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    controller: _sc3,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return const ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.cake,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        title: Text("Cake"),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyScrollProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  var enablePrimaryScroll = true;
  changePhysics({required bool enableScrolling}) {
    enablePrimaryScroll = enableScrolling;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[image: Output:]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use [Stickyheader](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers).

```
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers.dart';

ListView(
 shrinkwarp:true,
 children:[
  StickyHeader(
    head: Text('List 1 '),
    content : ListView.builder(
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(), // use this for clamping scroll 
        itemBuilder: (context, idx) => Container(),
        itemCount:5,
       )
 StickyHeader(
    head: Text('List 2 '),
    content : ListView.builder(
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(), // use this for clamping scroll 
        itemBuilder: (context, idx) => Container(),
        itemCount:5,
       )
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many easy ways to handle this situation as stated by many other developers. I have created an Example class with `ScrollController` and `AbsordPointer` classes to achieve the required behavior.

Sample

[image]

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  late ScrollController scrollController;
  var reachedAtEnd = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    scrollController =ScrollController()..addListener(() {
       if (scrollController.position.pixels == scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
       reachedAtEnd = true;
       setState(() {
         
       });
      }
    },);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 700,
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: scrollController,
              itemCount: 20,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.icecream,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                  title: Text("Ice Cream"),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 300,
            child: AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: !reachedAtEnd,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(
                      Icons.cake,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    title: Text("Cake"),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Usama this is not working on my end, I'm getting the same behavior as it was before.

Comment: Can you share the screen recording if it's working on your end?

Comment: Please try it now. I updated the code

Comment: Brother, I really  appreciate your efforts, but I don't want this behavior, What I want is, When you've scrolled all of your first list items, the First list should scroll upward because its parent is SingleChildScrollView and as you can see it's not  scrolling up.

Comment: Ok. It's easier to do with the current implementation. Just need to change physics of SingleChildScrollView with reachedAtEnd boolean flag.

Comment: Brother, it's not working, I checked it

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  // this variable determnines whether the back-to-top button is shown or not
  bool _showBackToTopButton = false;

  // scroll controller
  late ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController()
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          print(_scrollController.offset);
          if (_scrollController.offset >= 400) {
            _showBackToTopButton = true;
            // _scrollToTop();
            // show the back-to-top button
          } else {
            _showBackToTopButton = false; // hide the back-to-top button
          }
        });
      });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose(); // dispose the controller
    super.dispose();
  }

  // This function is triggered when the user presses the back-to-top button
  void _scrollToTop() {
    _scrollController.animateTo(0,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 3), curve: Curves.linear);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('com'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: 40,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          print(index);
          if (index == 39) {
            _scrollToTop();
          }
          return const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.icecream,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            title: Text(' Ice Cream'),
          );
        },
      ),

      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Shahzed, I appreciate your efforts but this is not the behavior that I want.Brother, what I want is, When you've scrolled all of your first list items, the First list should scroll upward because its parent is SingleChildScrollView and as you can see it's not scrolling up